# Get latest two post thumbnails on Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

what I'd like to do is to get the latest two posts on a specific category and show their thumbnails and title on top of the blog index.

Here's how I'd like to look like:
[How it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OCw91.png)

Here's how it is now:
[How it is now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2MbUg.png)

Code:

```
    <div class="destaques">
    <?php $args = array(
    'category_name' => 'Destaques',
    'posts_per_page' => 2,
    'order_by' => 'date',
    'order' => 'desc'
    );

    $post = get_posts( $args );
        if($post) {
            $post_id = $post[0]->ID;
            if(has_post_thumbnail($post_id)){
            echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post_id, array(379, 240), array('class' => 'post_thumbnail') );
            echo the_title ();
            }
            } ?>
</div>
```

How can I get two instead of just one? I can take care of styling if I can get them both to show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of single **if** block. You need to run a loop on two fetched posts.

A Simple Loop example is this

```
$myposts = get_posts( $args );

foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
<li>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
</li>
<?php endforeach; 
wp_reset_postdata();?>
```